# Gabor filters: large variance compared to the mean

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering

I am trying to extract Gabor features from an input image. So, I have setup a series of Gabor filters with different parameters (frequency, angle and standard deviation) and I am convolving each of these filters with the input image and looking at the mean and variance of the output magnitude image. So, in python it would look something like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as nd

# Here kernel is a given Gabor filter
def filter_image(self, image):
    filtered = np.zeros((len(self.kernels)*2,) + image.shape)        
    for k, kernel in enumerate(self.kernels):            
        filtered[k*2, :] = nd.convolve(image, np.real(kernel), mode='wrap')
        filtered[k*2+1, :] = nd.convolve(image, np.imag(kernel), mode='wrap')

return filtered
```

And now, I am looking at the mean and variance of the power image as:

```
def compute_features(self, image):
    features = np.zeros((len(self.kernels), 2))
    filtered = filter_image(image)
    for k in range(0, len(self.kernels)):
        power_image = np.sqrt(filtered[k*2]**2 + filtered[k*2+1]**2)
        features[k, 0] = filtered[k, :].mean()
        features[k, 1] = filtered[k, :].var()

return features
```

So, when I look at the mean and variance of the each of the filter responses, I notice that the variance is really high with respect to the mean. For example, I get values like (mean = 0.83, variance = 900). I wonder if this is something one sees often. Does this tell me that I do not really have any texture in the image? I am not sure how to interpret this.

I do apologize if this does not exactly belong on this forum. I did post this on crossvalidated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an idea about the texture of your image just by looking at them.

I suggest you have a look at the [example given in scikit-image documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_gabor.html). You'll be able to see typical results on texture images and to check your code.

I think there is a mistake in your code snippet: in your function `filter_image`, you are iterating over all the kernels, where you should be doing just one kernel convolution.

Besides this, you should check which type of image you use as input. In the skimage example, the image is **first converted to float**. The features are then all in [0, 1]. From your results, I suspect you're working with integers, which can yield very different values of mean and variance, though it give the same output after normalization.
If I change the code in the skimage example and use the raw integer images, I get results more like yours than with floats. I computed the min/max/mean ratios of mean over variance:

```
print((ref_feats[:, :, 0] / ref_feats[:, :, 1]).min())
print((ref_feats[:, :, 0] / ref_feats[:, :, 1]).mean())
print((ref_feats[:, :, 0] / ref_feats[:, :, 1]).max())
```

(where ref_feats is a table of (mean, var) over the images and kernels) and got this:

```
0.00403515106897
1.67550281887
9.91940408151
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into the integer/float issue but there should be implicit casting anyway somehow. However, one **needs** to convolve with each of the kernels. This is also done in the example you refer (look in the compute_feats function). The idea is that each of these filters is sensitive to some particular frequency and orientation.

Comment: Think you are onto something with the conversion to float thing! I just checked with the example and it does indeed make a huge difference to the values. I wonder why the scaling of the image to 0.0-1.0 makes such a difference.

Comment: @Luca, i agree you have to convolve with each of the kernels, of course. But you iterate on all kernels in both your functions, there must be something wrong (maybe a copy-paste issue -- the self.kernels looks wrong)

Comment: @Luca, and about the integer/float, it's not only casting, it's also normalizing to [0,1] values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, in the second loop it is a copy/paste issue. Good catch! Yes, why should the normalisation make a difference with the mean and standard deviation? I thought their ratios should remain the same or am I mistaken and they also scale?

Comment: To elaborate: I can see that if different features are not on the same scale, they cannot be compared easily but why should the variance of a single filter response be magnitudes higher than the mean when the input image is not normalised between 0 and 1?